# How to override 'apply' in a Function with multiple parameter lists?

Tags: scala, currying

I'm trying to make an instance of this type of function object:

```
trait CanGetSiblingDock[S, D]
  extends (D => String => S => Option[D])
```

with this:

```
implicit val getSiblingDock = new CanGetSiblingDock[Situation, Dock] {
  def apply(dock: Dock)(siblingName: String)(sit: Situation): Option[Dock] = ???
}
```

The compiler objects:

```
error: object creation impossible, since method apply in trait Function1 of type (v1: FARG.Dock)String => (TestFARGModel4.this.Situation => Option[FARG.Dock]) is not defined
(Note that T1 does not match FARG.Dock)
  implicit val getSiblingDock = new CanGetSiblingDock[Situation, Dock] {
                                    ^
```

If I understand this correctly, the compiler is complaining that the first argument of `apply` is not of type `Dock`. It appears to me, though, that it is.

Obviously, I'm misunderstanding something somewhere. How do you *correctly* make an instance of a Function with multiple parameter lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
scala> trait F extends (String => Int => Int)
defined trait F

scala> object X extends F { def apply(s: String): Int => Int = ??? }
defined object X
```

Comment: Basically, you're curried? Yes, `A=>B=>C` means `A=>(B=>C)`.

Comment: This works! Wow, it's been two years since I first used Scala, and I still can't guess the syntax for things I haven't tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The type `A => B => C` is not `Function2[A, B, C]`, for which the `apply` method would be `def apply(a: A, b: B): C`. But instead this is `Function1[A, Function1[B, C]]`, like a curried function. If you want a `Function2`, you would have to write:

```
trait Foo extends Function2[Int, String, Boolean] {
  override def apply(a: Int, b: String): Boolean = ???
}
```

If now you want multiple parameter lists, you would have to overload `apply`:

```
trait Foo extends Function2[Int, String, Boolean] {
  override def apply(a: Int, b: String): Boolean = ???

  def apply(a: Int)(b: String): Boolean = apply(a, b)
}
```

This is not possible because after erasure, both methods would look the same on the byte code level.

Comment: I'll comment as I did to the other guy, Basically, you're curried? Well, it's defined at http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#function-types that it's right-associative.